# PHP - lost session after an ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am trying to implement an "Add friend" button on a user's profile page, for my social network. When clicked, it should send an AJAX request, and change it's value. There are four possible values: "Add friend", "Cancel request", "Remove Friend" and "Accept friend".

I keep the user's ID in the session variable, as well as the ID of the user whose profile is currently being viewed.

This is my code:

```
(function (jQuery) {
var friendButton = $('.friend_button');
friendButton.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        buttonClicked = self.attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../php/profile.php',
        data: { 'buttonClicked': buttonClicked },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            self.attr('name', data['name'].trim());
            self.attr('value', data['value'].trim());
        }
    });
});
```

})($);

And this is my server-side:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    if ($_POST['buttonClicked']) {
        if (!session_id()){
                session_save_path($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/tmp");
                session_start();  
            }
        if ($_POST['buttonClicked'] === 'remove_friend'){
            session_save_path($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/tmp");
            if (!session_id()){
                session_start();  
            }
            remove_friend_db($conn, $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['current_id']);
            echo json_encode(array('name' => 'add_friend', 'value' => 'Add friend'));
        }//end of checking remove_friend

        if ($_POST['buttonClicked'] === 'add_friend'){

            if (!session_id()){
                session_save_path($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/tmp");
                session_start();  
            }
            add_request($conn, $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['current_id']);
            echo json_encode(array('name' => 'cancel_request', 'value' => 'Cancel request'));
        }//end of checking add_friend

        if ($_POST['buttonClicked'] === 'cancel_request'){

            if (!session_id()){
                session_save_path($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/tmp");
                session_start();  
            }
            cancel_request_db($conn, $_SESSION['id']);
            echo json_encode(array('name' => 'add_friend', 'value' => 'Add friend'));
        }//end of checking cancel_request

        if ($_POST['buttonClicked'] === 'accept_friend'){
            session_save_path($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/tmp");
            if (!session_id()){
                session_start();  
            }
            add_friendship($conn, $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['current_id']);
            echo json_encode(array('name' => 'remove_friend', 'value' => 'Remove friend'));
        }//end of checking accept_friend


    }//end of checking buttonClicked
}//end of checking POST
```

Now, the problem is that when I click "Add friend" for the first time, everything works perfectly well. Request is sent to a database, and the button changes it's value to "Cancel request". Then, when I click "Cancel request", everything still works fine, request is deleted from the database, and the button changes it's value to "Add friend", again.

But, when I click on "Add friend" again (for the second time), it sends an AJAX request, but my session variables are empty, and request can't be inserted into a database. If i refresh the page, the situation is the same, buttons work only the first time.

So why are the session variables empty?

Here is the form:

```
<form action="../php/profile.php" method="post">
            <?php if (is_friend($conn, $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['current_id'])) : ?>
                <input class="friend_button" type="submit" name="remove_friend" value="Remove friend">

            <?php elseif  (is_sent_request($conn, $_SESSION['id'])) : ?>
                <input class="friend_button sent" type="submit" name="cancel_request" value="Friend request sent">

            <?php elseif  (requested_friendship($conn, $_SESSION['id'])) : ?>
                <input class="friend_button" type="submit" name="accept_friend" value="Accept friendship">

            <?php else : ?>
                <input class="friend_button" type="submit" name="add_friend" value="Add friend">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </form>
```

**EDIT:** I've now realized that only $_SESSION['current_id'] is being lost. I get it's value from a query string. But I still don't understand what's going on.

**EDIT2:** Anyway, I don't know how to resolve this problem, so I've modified my code. I've concatenated the user's ID to a button name attribute. For example, name="add_friend-2", or name="cancel_request-2". Before AJAX request, I split that string, and then send the button name and the ID separately. In server-side, I process the request, with the given ID and my own ID (which remained in the session variable), and then return the user's ID, and in AJAX callback, I concatenate it back to a new button name. Everything works fine now, but I'm still confused with that session problem.

Comment: holy redundancy, batman :p ever thought of putting session-start and save path info at the top of your script?

Comment: Well, I did, of course, it didn't work.

Comment: **Zowie!!** I wasn't going to ask [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066634/php-lost-session-after-an-ajax-request#comment35249412_23066634); they never put in that tiny bit of information *even though it's hidden in there somewhere*. Well, I'm off to see Spiderman 2 now, *pass the popcorn please*.

Comment: do you start the session in all your scripts ?

Comment: post your HTML of the form

Comment: I do start the session in all my scripts.

Comment: When I start the session at the top of the page, it doesn't work. When I put the session_start() in every block for itself, it works, but just once.

Comment: Their sessions are only executed on some "IFs", add `session_start` and `session_save_path` in "header" (at the beginning of PHP outside of "IFs").

Comment: Well, as I've said, I've done that, and then nothing worked at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i did was to firstly set_flashdata($data) then at the end of ajax call function or controller again set the data in flashdata() this way the data will be available to you every time your ajax call repeats it self.